# How do I singularize and lemmatize an entire pandas dataframe column using TextBlob?

Tags: python, pandas, text, data-cleaning, lemmatization

I have a pandas dataframe that contains the following columns: df['adjectives'], df['nouns'], and df['adverbs']. Each of these columns contains lists of tokens based on their respective parts of speech.

I would like to use TextBlob to create three new columns in my data frame, df['adjlemmatized'], df['nounlemmatized'], and df['advlemmatized'].

Each of these columns should contain wordlists consisting of words in their singularized, lemma form.

I have tried following the TextBlob documentation, but I am stuck writing functions that will iterate over my entire dataframe.

```py
Words Inflection and Lemmatization

Each word in TextBlob.words or Sentence.words is a Word object (a subclass of unicode) with useful methods, e.g. for word inflection.

>>> sentence = TextBlob('Use 4 spaces per indentation level.')
>>> sentence.words
WordList(['Use', '4', 'spaces', 'per', 'indentation', 'level'])
>>> sentence.words[2].singularize()
'space'
>>> sentence.words[-1].pluralize()
'levels'
Words can be lemmatized by calling the lemmatize method.

>>> from textblob import Word
>>> w = Word("octopi")
>>> w.lemmatize()
'octopus'
>>> w = Word("went")
>>> w.lemmatize("v")  # Pass in WordNet part of speech (verb)
'go'
```

---

Here is the code I used to get the parts of speech from my text:

```py
# get adjectives
def get_adjectives(text):
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    print(text)
    return [word for (word,tag) in blob.tags if tag.startswith("JJ")]
df['adjectives'] = df['clean_reviews'].apply(get_adjectives)
```

Comment: What columns does you dataframe currently have? one for adjectives, one for nouns and one for adverbs?

Comment: Yes, but I also have one that contains the text itself from which the POS wordlists were derived.

Answer (score 0):

If your words are already tokenized and you want to keep them that way, it's easy:

```
df['adjlemmatized'] = df.adjectives.apply(lambda x: [ TextBlob(w) for w in x])
df['adjlemmatized'] = df.adjlemmatized.apply(lambda x: [ w.lemmatize() for w in x])
```

Comment: Both of these are throwing the error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lemmatize'"

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the `TextBlob`, now I've edited it. If this doesn't work, please post a sample of your data as is usual on this site

Comment: Now receiving a syntax error. Please see the link for a sample of my data. http://www.filedropper.com/sample_2

Comment: I split it into two steps, but I think the error was because of an extra parenthesis. I don't have `Textblob` installed here, so I can't test my code. Is it working now?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I am still running into this error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lemmatize'"

Comment: I  am posting the function I used to get the parts of speech to the main text. Perhaps this function could be modified to get the lemma?

Comment: Sorry, again I had a little typo. Is it working now? Sorry I can't troubleshoot my own code, haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197638/discussion-between-youngguv-and-juan-c).